# prettyPrint() function does not work after a page is loaded

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, google-code-prettify

I am using `google-code-prettify` through CDN  `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>` as mentioned in faq over [here](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) `prettyPrint()`
 is the function which highlights code.
Now i am having problems

`prettyPrint()` when i call this function it says not defined
cdn automatically calls this function when page loads and highlights syntax but after loading i am changing content of codes then i want it to highlight again. But i am unable to that with `prettyPrint()` function.

i self hosted `google-code-prettify` and then i used `prettyPrint()` and it worked fine but when i call this function after i change my code nothing happens it doesn't highlights my syntax

> Here is the code i am using

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Developer Query</title>
<link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
<style>
/*This CSS applied button in which section user is visiting. */
ul#nav > li#btn2 {
    border-top: 3px solid #FF9900;
    border-left: 2px solid grey;
    border-right: 2px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
/*Button CSS is end. */ 
.content{
    width:1136px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
input#question_title{
    margin:20px auto;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
textarea#question_content{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
#preview{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php include_once('php_include/header.php'); ?>
<div class="content">
    <input type="text" name="question_title" id="question_title" placeholder="What happed with your code?" />
    <textarea id="question_content" name="question_content" placeholder="Elabrote your code" onKeyUp="render();"></textarea>
    <h3>Here's what it look like</h3>
    <code class="prettyprint"><div id="preview">&lt;html&gt;</div></code>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
//HELPER FUNCTIONS////
function $(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function render(){//
    var question_content = $("question_content").value;
    //Sanitizing data//
    var entitles = {//List of all Html entitiles
        '<':"&lt;",
        '>':"&gt;",
        '\n':"<br>",        
    }
    question_content = question_content.replace(/<|>|\n/gi, function (html_ent){return entitles[html_ent];});
    var preview = $("preview");
    preview.innerHTML = question_content;   
    //prettyPrint();
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML, including where you use prettify. It may be a DOM issue.

Comment: updated question with my code

Comment: I don't see the place where you actually include the script. Is there a

`<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>` 
in your code or something similar?

Comment: @andrewFan updated again

Answer (score 0):

When `prettyprint()` is run, it adds the "prettyprinted" class to each element it changes. If you need to reapply `prettyprint()`, remove the "prettyprinted" class first, then call `prettyprint()`.